# What is the purpose of \summary in tex?

Tags: latex, tex, tex-live

I have to write a report using LaTeX for my final year project at university. Having been given some example documents to learn to use it, a common command, \summary, keeps appearing. However, what's written inside the summary doesn't appear anywhere in the produced document. Is it some kind of internal documentation?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal example of the code that uses this `\summary` command? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, and you should provide links to class files/packages that are not standard/available on [CTAN](//ctan.org).

Answer (score 0):

With a quick google, it is likely that `/summary` is used as a shortcut to reuse the abstract in one place.

Looking at a few templates : [ucl thesis template](http://www.ulo.ucl.ac.uk/obsmag/templates/obs_thesis.tex), [book template](https://github.com/prideout/book-webgl/blob/master/latex/book.tex#L159) and [stackoverflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246684/formatting-a-thesis-summary-chapter) it tends to be a custom command used for repeated style. Look through the different files for "summary" to see if appears in the preamble somewhere.

Comment: You are correct, it's from the .cls file that was provided for the document styling. I an completely new to TeX, and had assumed the environment was part of TeX itself. I'm still not totally sure what it does, so here's the definition if you can help:



`\newcommand{\summary}[1]{\renewcommand{\@summary{#1}}`
`\newcommand{\@summary}{\ClassError{cmpfinalreport}{No\string\summary\space given}{}}`

Comment: There is another piece of code that generates the abstract, which uses \summary, later on in the .cls file.